# How to convert currency value in UI using currenct button ,without storing value in store redux

Tags: reactjs

I Have one shopping_cart app where I am storing itemName and price in table

Using currency dropdown button in header i am converting price value, based on selection (USD,INR,EUR) it will convert price value

I am using redux and storing data in store ,

My Question is -- I want to change currency convert logic in view part not in store (redux),currently everytime i select option from dropdown value is getting updated in store but i want to update value in view(UI) only not to save in store

New in react and Stack

Comment: use context API its really helpful to achieve that type of thing in your whole application.

Comment: Can I use redux-store and context-api both.
For example -- when first time my app load then data store in redux section after that if i use currency convertor dropdown then all data exchange shoul happen in context lvl ?